# SFMC query syntax

Tags: marketing-cloud, compile-error, saql

Greeting All,

New to the SFMC application and have been assigned as the new admin.  In some of the queries I am having difficulty understanding the purpose of the syntax and I am hoping someone here can shed some light on the syntax for me:

1. `row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ld.email ORDER BY opp.createddate DESC) AS row_num`
2. `AND opp.createddate > COALESCE((SELECT MAX(cost_date) FROM test_Journey_Subs WITH (nolock)),'2015-06-29')`

When would you need to use the **partition by** and **coalesce** syntax?
Is there a resource that list all of the functions/syntax used in SFMC?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally use [over/partition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) in the SFMC Query Activities to explicitly select one of several duplicates in a result set.  You can also use it to assign a numeric value to a row based on the criteria in the `by` and `order by` part of the clause.

The [coalesce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function is used to find the first non-null value in a result set separated by commas.

Just as a clarification, Salesforce Marketing Cloud Query Activities are limited to certain a [Transact-SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563(v=sql.90).aspx) syntax.  All of that is outlined on this page: [Query Activities](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)

Comment: Awesome explanations and appreciate the links to the references.  This should get me going in the right direction.                                                       Thanks Michael

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working with Salesforce's Wave Analytics (i'll just be calling it Wave for short).

Wave is not exclusive to the Salesforce Marketing Cloud, and has its own query language dialect called SAQL (which is different than the SOQL and SOSL query dialects used in the various Salesforce 'clouds').

There is [documentation about SAQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_intro.htm) which should answer general questions about the syntax and basic usage of each syntax element.

I'm not familiar with SAQL myself. The SAQL documentation doesn't seem to cover `partition by` very well, but it does have a page for `coalesce`.

`Coalesce` has 2 uses:

- Automatically replace `null` values with a specified default value
- Find the first non-null value in a collection of values ([the coalesce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bi_dev_guide_saql.meta/bi_dev_guide_saql/bi_saql_functions_coalesce.htm) seems to have a decent example of this usage)

I had to do some research on `Partition By`. Generally speaking, the concepts and terminology used in the Salesforce query dialects will have analogs in SQL (Structured Query Language). Searching the web for the meaning/use of something in SQL would be a good place to start in this situation.

My (very limited) understanding of `Partition By` is that it's used to basically create sub-groups (sub-windows?) in an aggregate function. I found a [somewhat helpful explanation in some product blog](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/11/03/probably-the-coolest-sql-feature-window-functions/).

A crude and very contrived example might be that given a set of Opportunities

```
Opp # | Amount | StageName
-------------------------- 
1     | $10    | 1 - Working
2     | $20    | 3 - Committed 
3     | $30    | 3 - Committed 
4     | $40    | 4 - Closed Won 
5     | $10    | 5 - Closed Lost 
6     | $5     | 5 - Closed Lost 
7     | $15    | 5 - Closed Lost
```

If you simply `sum(Amount) as Total`, you'd get

```
row    | Total
1      | $130
```

If you `sum(Amount) OVER([..] PARTITION BY StageName ORDER BY StageName) as Total`, you'd get

```
row    | StageName       | Total
1      | 1 - Working     | $10
2      | 3 - Committed   | $50 
3      | 4 - Closed Won  | $40
4      | 5 - Closed Lost | $30
```

In SQL (and SOQL), you could accomplish the same thing using a `GROUP BY` statement like `[SELECT SUM(Amount) Total FROM Opportunity GROUP BY StageName]`, but there are apparently benefits to doing this via partitioning.